# Does consistency type matter for

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, consistency, eventual-consistency

If I write a new key/value to dynamodb, will the result differ in case of reading it in "Strong consistency" mode or "Eventual consistency" mode?

I mean it is a new key/value which is never going to get updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to read they key/object back right after your write it, by the same or another process, its not going to matter.

Comment: What if I need to read it right after I write? My question is mainly whether the consistency matters for updates only? If I write and then read immediately, can eventual consistency say that the key doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, it can, though the documentation states that the typical duration would be less than 1 second, so your definition of "immediately" could be significant.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for an eventually consistent read to still return null in this case. The documentation does say 1 sec propagation delay in general, but it is not a guarantee. If your application critically depends on reading the latest version of the item, then you will want to use strongly consistent reads.